# My spinner is not showing my selected value

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Any idea why my spinner is not showing my selected value, but when I scroll the scrollbar,the table in which the spinner is inserted, it suddenly shows up and proceed to my item selected function? I already search google but I didn't found any solutions. Please help me, guys. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code for creating the dynamic spinner inside a table:

```
public override View GetView(int row, int column, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        KeyValuePair<int, T> id_type = table[row + 1].Values.ElementAt(column + 1);
            switch (id_type.Value.ToString())
            {
                case "spin1":
                    convertView = new Spinner(context);
                    ((Spinner)convertView).Id = id_type.Key;
                    ((Spinner)convertView).SetMinimumWidth(100);
                    ((Spinner)convertView).ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(cmb_select);
                    freqadp = new ArrayAdapter(context, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, freqarr);
                    freqadp.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
                    ((Spinner)convertView).Adapter = freqadp;
                    break;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to set selected item in the spinner you need to set it using `SetSelection` method:

```
((Spinner)convertView).SetSelection(0) //This will set the first item as selected.
```